# Can't access to my meteor app deployed on centOS from internet with different port

Tags: linux, apache, meteor, centos, port

I have a CentOS 6.6 environment set up on Rackspace. I am running LAMP stack on the same machine. SeLinux is disabled.

I installed meteor as I always do to server and start meteor sample app just by typing meteor as always. On console, I don't see an error. It says

```
 App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

as it should. However, when I go to my ip address as `http://IP.IP.IP.IP:3000`I can't see my meteor app. Not an error, not a warning. Just nothing to show.

I tried turning off httpd service in any case and run my app on port 80. It worked.

My question: how can I enable other ports accessible for meteor apps on CentOS 6.6? All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to create an IPTABLES rule for other ports

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

You can use a GUI `sudo system-config-firewall-tui` to give it a go too in case you have other rules with the port 3000.

Comment: no chance unfortunately, nothing changed on browser.

Comment: My bad, disabling firewall again worked actually. Checking as answer.